# Assembly error A2119

Tags: windows, assembly

Sou um iniciante em *Assembly* e estou agora a tentar correr o meu primeiro programa *Hello World*. Uso o Windows 7 e o MASM.

Estou seguindo um tutorial a fonte do program até o seguinte:

```all
.386
model falt, stdcall
option casemap:none

include     \masm32\include\windows.inc

include     \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

include     \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib  \masm\lib\user32.lib

.data
msg db "Hello World!!!", 0
cpt db "MY FIRST PROGRAM!!!", 0

.code
start:
invoke MessageBox, NULL, ADDR msg, ADDR cpt, MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess, NULL
end start
```

Ao mandar o editor *assemblar* o código fonte, recebo os seguintes erros:

> \masm32\include\windows.inc(78) : error A2119: language type must be specified
>       \masm32\include\windows.inc(79) : error A2119: language type must be specified
>       \masm32\include\windows.inc(80) : error A2119: language type must be specified
>       \masm32\include\windows.inc(81) : error A2119: language type must be specified
>       \masm32\include\windows.inc(82) : error A2119: language type must be specified
>       ...
>       ...

Alguém sabe o que o erro significa?

Answer (score 2):

Existem três erros.

- Os dois primeiros erros estão na segunda linha, `model falt, stdcall`, você deve colocar o ponto `.` na frente do `model`, ficando [`.model`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss9fh0d6.aspx) e usar `flat` no lugar de `falt`.
- O último erro está na decima linha, `includelib  \masm\lib\user32.lib` deve ser `includelib  \masm32\lib\user32.lib`, faltou o *32* na frente de *masm*.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```all
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include     \masm32\include\windows.inc

include     \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

include     \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
msg db "Hello World!!!", 0
cpt db "MY FIRST PROGRAM!!!", 0

.code
start:
invoke MessageBox, 0h, ADDR msg, ADDR cpt, MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess, 0h
end start
```